# How to read an XML file using Testcomplete?

Tags: testcomplete

I have an XML file of the following format:
    `<a>Test</a>`
    `<Book>`
      `<Title>ABC</Title>`
      `<Price>123</Price>`
      `<Author>Pete</Author>`
    `</Book>`
Is there anyway to read the contents using TC9 (jscript)? The xml file that i am using doesnot have a namespace.It is saved as .XML file but cannot be opened using web browser.It is basically used by us to store Logs of our app hence can be viewed via Notepad or Notepad++ .
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can find detailed information on how to work with XML files from a TestComplete script in the [Working With XML Files From Scripts](http://smartbear.com/viewarticle/57106/) help topic.
The only concern I see is that the XML file you showed us does not have a root node. It must have a root node in order to make standard XML parsers work with it.